# Scenekit: Angle between two SCNNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, scenekit

I am trying to develop a robotic arm tracking system.
I used scenekit to develop the visualization and the control of the system.
The SCNNodes of my system is:

Shoulder--->Upper_arm--->Fore_arm--->Palm.

I could now rotate each node using the `rotation property of each SCNNode.`

And I am now interested in whether there's any existing API to `compute the angle between two SCNNode` when the system is moving, eg. the angle between the Upper_arm and Fore_arm?

Comment: I don't see why you would have to calculate it. Each node's local transform is defined relative to its parent. If the forearm node parent is the upper arm node (which it should be), then you can just read the rotation on whatever axis you are interested in.

Comment: @KarlSigiscar You are right! Thanks for the elaborate explanation. It gave me more understanding of the mechanism. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`SCNNode.eulerAngles`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407980-eulerangles?language=objc), you will get `SCNVector3`, which has components:

- Pitch (the x component) is the rotation about the node’s x-axis.
- Yaw (the y component) is the rotation about the node’s y-axis.
- Roll (the z component) is the rotation about the node’s z-axis.

`Fore_arm.eulerAngles` will give you rotation angles relative to `Upper_arm`